# Image Optimize Field - adding ImOp field to a volume causes images in that volume to not be found

Tags: plugin-imageoptimize

Steps I've taken to configure Image Optimize

- Installed plugin, configured binaries (green checkmarks all around)
- from the CLI, ran `./craft resave/assets` - all assets resaved and successful example: `- Resaving Female (474749) ... done`
- created new OptimizedImages field "Optimized Images Field (Square)"
- assigned this field to the Asset Volume Field Layout for our site content
- from the CLI, ran `./craft resave/assets`- all assets from that volume now are unable to be found
  `- Resaving Female (474749) ... error: The file "female.jpg" does not exist.`

similarly, the CLI command for the plugin to run variants breaks the same way:

running `./craft image-optimize/optimize/create` results in:

```
196/213 - processing asset: Female from field: Optimized Images Field (square)
[error]: The file "female.jpg" does not exist. while processing 196/213 - processing asset: Female from field: Optimized Images Field (square)
```

We've cleared caches, tried on fresh volumes, etc... same results whenever we add the Optimize Image Field to the volume.

We are still able to create front-end variants in twig, but none using the ImOp field.

> Craft CMS 3.4.15 
>   Image Optimize 1.6.12

Any recommendations on where to go from here?  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: So I'm unclear if ImageOptimize is affecting anything here; can you uninstall the plugin, and then try running `./craft resave/assets` to see if you get the same error? It seems like a particular asset that Craft is having issues with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked with @andrew.welch and found that, although our site is using `/html` for the webroot, there also existed a `/web` folder.  For a reason not yet identified, the plugin brought the `/web` folder to the surface as it was attempting to look in that folder.  I simply deleted the `/web` folder, and everything works.

The file `craftcms/cms/src/console/Request.php` sets the path based on what folders it finds on the filesystem, and "web" is before "html" in the array that it checks

```
    foreach (['web', 'public', 'public_html', 'html'] as $folder) {
        if (is_dir($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $folder)) {
            $dir .= DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $folder;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Thank you Andrew!